# Typescript - Import class with path alias failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm in the middle of trying Typescript with OvernightJS and having problem trying to import a class into my controller, got an error saying :

> Error: Cannot find module '@Models/company'

Somehow when I changed the import to '../models/company' and it works. Also importing '@Models/firebase' works fine too.

UserController :

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@overnightjs/core'
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import CompanyModel from '@Models/company'

@Controller('api/company')
export class CompanyController {
  private readonly company = new CompanyModel()

  @Get()
  private async get(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> {
    const companies = await this.company.getAllCompanies()

    return res.status(200).json({
      data: {
        companies
      }
    })
  }
}
```

CompanyModelClass :

```
import * as firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin'
import { Firestore, QuerySnapshot, QueryDocumentSnapshot } from '@Models/firebase'

class CompanyModel {
  private readonly firestore: Firestore

  constructor () {
    this.firestore = firebaseAdmin.firestore()
  }

  async getAllCompanies() {
    return await new Promise((resolve: any) => {
      this.firestore.collection('/companies').onSnapshot((snapshot: QuerySnapshot) => {
        const docs = snapshot.docs.map((doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => {
          return doc.data()
        })

        resolve(docs)
      })
    })
  }
}

export default CompanyModel
```

tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@Models/*": ["models/*"]
    },
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "api-with-overnightjs",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts",
    "deploy": "now --target production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@overnightjs/core": "^1.4.7",
    "@overnightjs/jwt": "^1.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^7.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/express-jwt": "^0.0.42",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-security": "^1.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.8.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks and appreciate a lot!

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: how do i import class in typescript? did i missed out any typescript related config?

Comment: Just to confirm - file name of `CompanyModel` is `company.ts`?

Comment: yes it is. i've just found the problem, need to add tsconfig-paths into run script so that custom paths get registered. appreciate the feedback still. :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue solved when added [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) into run scripts :

```
"dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.ts' --exec 'ts-node' -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts"
```

Comment: you could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsmon which is very fast on reloading

`tsmon src/index.ts`.